# Pulling image from local docker repository

Tags: docker, kubernetes, docker-registry, minikube

### Cannot pull image from local repository inside Minikube

I have a local docker repository set up on my local machine (mac). I only have two images stored in there.
I'm setting up various containers with Kubernetes definition files and on of my configurations is a replication controller that pulls the image from my repository which works fine. The other is a PetSet which pulls from the same repository but fails. UGH!!!

When I push to my local repository I use:

```
localhost:5000/image/name:v1
```

and when I reference the image from my Kubernetes configuration I use:

```
{local ip addr}:5000/image/name:v1
```

If I SSH into my Minikube instance and try to manually pull the image I get the following: `Error response from daemon: read tcp 10.0.2.15:51958->{my local ip addr}:5000: read: connection reset by peer`

This has been working fine until today.

When I start my Minikube VM I add the flag

```
--insecure-registry={ip addr of my machine}:5000
```

So far I've tried

- Deleting the minikube and .minikube directory (multiple times)
- Deleting and recreating my local repository
- Completely reinstalling Minikube

I'm currently at a complete loss as to why one image is successfully pulled from the local repository and the other fails.

Comment: The RC pulls from image1 and petset from image2 - is that what you are saying? And manually doing `docker pull image1` works and `docker pull image2` doesnt?

Comment: Right... so 
RC pulls `{local machine IP}:5000/image name`- works
PetSet pulls `{local machine IP}:5000/petset image name` - FAILS

And like I said, if I try to do a docker pull from within MiniKube on the PetSet base image it fails too, but the RC base image works fine...
VERY WEIRD!

Comment: Are you able to pull the petset image locally on your box?

Comment: yep... Can pull and push to local Repository from my Mac.

Comment: is it a big image perhaps?

Comment: It's about 2 gigs, but normally (when this was working) I could see my CPU workload really increase during the time it was pulling the image. When I do it now, it does nothing.

Answer (score 1):

So, it turns out that the version of VirtualBox I was running was causing the problem. I was running VirtualBox version `5.0.28-r111378`, but after downgrading to an earlier release `5.0.20-r106931` the problem was solved. You can view the thread that addressed this issue [here](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/27734)